# How can I get a stacked bar with single values and sum on the side

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels, bar-chart

Based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129629/how-can-i-get-a-stacked-bar-with-single-values-and-sum-on-top) question I was able to put partial and total values on my bar plot. My bars have some really small values though and it is impossible to fit the numbers in some ranges. I would like to shift those label on the side. How can I do?

Note that in one case I have two consecutive small ranges, so it would be awesome have those values on alternate sides.

Thanks in advance!

Here is what I have so far:

[image]

And the related code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{
        show sum on top/.style={
            /pgfplots/scatter/@post marker code/.append code={%
                \node[
                at={(normalized axis cs:%
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x},%
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y})%
                },
                anchor=south,
                ]
                {\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}};
            },
        },
    }
    
    \begin{axis}[ybar stacked,
        nodes near coords,
        title={Energy spent},
        xtick={0,...,4},
        bar width=25pt,
        ymin=0,
        enlarge x limits=0.125,
        ylabel = Energy (J),
        legend entries={A,
            B,
            C,
            D},
        legend pos=outer north east,
    ]
    
    \addplot[fill=blue!80] coordinates 
    {(0,0) (1,0) (2,20.544) (3,21.192)};
    \addplot[fill=cyan!80] coordinates 
    {(0,0) (1,0) (2,9.610) (3,9.681)};
    \addplot[fill=red!80] coordinates 
    {(0,0.505) (1,12.505) (2,0.247) (3,1.975)};
    \addplot[fill=pink!80, show sum on top] coordinates 
    {(0,3.772) (1,1.075) (2,0.439) (3,2.066)};
    
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: There's an answer that gives some material on placing numbers on the side of the graph [in a horizontal scenario](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151460/single-stacked-bar-values-and-legend?rq=1). Perhaps it can give some hints to move forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this one is a bit tricky to solve from the doc's `nodes near coords align` in combination with `visualization depends on` should have been the silver bullet. Weirdly it fails.

Instead one must combine `visualization depends on` with `every node near coord/.append style` as a work around.

One must also include their data inline, as explained by [@Symbol1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/287558/14593), to prevent errors.

```
Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `thisrow_unavailable_load_table_directly' (in 'thisrow_unavailable_load_table_directly')
```

I also had to restructure the data into a table form. I supposed one could have used meta tags with the original coordinate data but I haven't tried this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{
        show sum on top/.style={
            /pgfplots/scatter/@post marker code/.append code={%
                \node[
                at={(normalized axis cs:%
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x},%
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y})%
                },
                anchor=south,
                ]
                {\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}};
            },
        },
    }

    \begin{axis}[ybar stacked,
        nodes near coords,
        title={Energy spent},
        xtick={0,...,4},
        bar width=25pt,
        ymin=0,
        enlarge x limits=0.125,
        ylabel = Energy (J),
        legend entries={A,
            B,
            C,
            D},
        legend pos=outer north east,
    ]

    \addplot+[visualization depends on={value \thisrow{Ax} \as \xdelta},
              visualization depends on={value \thisrow{Ay} \as \ydelta},
              every node near coord/.append style={xshift=\xdelta,yshift=\ydelta}] table [x={x}, y={A}] {
      x A      Ax Ay 
      0 0      0  0  
      1 0      0  0  
      2 20.544 0  0  
      3 21.192 0  0  
    };
    \addplot+[visualization depends on={value \thisrow{Bx} \as \xdelta},
              visualization depends on={value \thisrow{By} \as \ydelta},
              every node near coord/.append style={xshift=\xdelta,yshift=\ydelta}] 
     table [x={x}, y={B}] {
      x B     Bx By    
      0 0     0  0     
      1 0     0  0     
      2 9.610 0  0   
      3 9.681 0  0     
    };
    \addplot+[visualization depends on={value \thisrow{Cx} \as \xdelta},
              visualization depends on={value \thisrow{Cy} \as \ydelta},
              every node near coord/.append style={xshift=\xdelta,yshift=\ydelta}] 
     table [x={x}, y={C}] {
      x C      Cx  Cy 
      0 0.505  25  5  
      1 12.505 0   0  
      2 0.247  -25 -10  
      3 1.975  -25 -10  
    };
    \addplot+[visualization depends on={value \thisrow{Dx} \as \xdelta},
              visualization depends on={value \thisrow{Dy} \as \ydelta},
              every node near coord/.append style={xshift=\xdelta,yshift=\ydelta},
              show sum on top] 
     table [x={x}, y={D}] {
      x D      Dx  Dy
      0 3.772  0   0 
      1 1.075 -25  0 
      2 0.439 -25  0
      3 2.066 -25  0
    };

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Note pgfplots has sensible enough defaults so I inserted the `+` between `\addplot` and the options `[]` hence the [image: resulting] colours differ slightly.